# PHP forms clearing after sumbit

Tags: php, forms, isset

I want to be able to clear the fields after and when someone sends a form to the server mail. But instead the input remains. even after refresh.

Comment: What's your current code that keeps the fields filled?

Answer (score 1):

Echo out some javascript to call `form.reset()` when the page load completes. You may want to use a `$_GET` parameter to identify when you should do this (e.. after a successful POST request to the same URI).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a reset button in your form and auto clicked it on refresh of form or submit of the form

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you'll need to set the values of the form inputs back to their defaults (empty strings, or first entry in drop-down etc.) using javascript.

The easiest way to do this is by using the `form.Reset()` method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) when you submit the form by putting it in the `onSubmit()` event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm1" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="this.reset()">
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually in this case it makes no sense, as in your example, on submit a reload happens, and thus the form is already cleared. I guess he is using ajax or some frames model that indeed can be helped by `this.reset();`

Comment: Yes, you're right about `reset()` being redundant on a reload. Hopefully adding `reset()` to whatever function is being called on the `onsubmit` event will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_destroy()` or `unset()` functions

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the inputs and the reset button will reset all fields.

```
<form name="form1" action="form.php">
     <input type="text" name="f_nme" value="<?php echo $_POST["f_nme"]; ?>">
     <input type="text" name="l_nme" value="<?php echo $_POST["l_nme"]; ?>">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$_REQUEST = array()` OR `$_POST = array()` OR `$_GET = array()` (based on the type of **method** used) after the message sent/transaction done .This can be used to clear the post,get, request **array** after a successful request.But if your form is **asynchronous** you may need to use `form.reset()` on page load.

Answer (score -1):

Set `autocomplete='off'` for the input fields.

You can follow Post/Redirect/Get approach if you don't want the form to resubmit the same values on refresh.